# Filter and bind the data to the Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Data-table and binding the Large unsorted object data to datatable. My code is below:

```
 var ExpenceDataTableElement = $('#ExpenceDataTable').DataTable({
 data: Data,
 pageLength: 10,
 "bSort": false,
 "autoWidth": false,
 columns: [{
      "className":"clsAction",
      "data": "TimesheetUID",
      "title": "Action",
      "render": (data, type, row) => '<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />',
      "width": "4%",
      "visible":true
 },
 {
      "className":"clsPeriodName",
      "data": "PeriodName",
      "title": "Timesheet Name",
      "visible":true
 },
 { 
      "className":"clsTSPeriodStatus",
      "data": "Open",
      "title": "Timesheet Period <br> Status",
      "render":function(data,type,row){ if(data == 1){return " Open"}else{return " close"}},
      "width": "10%",
      "visible":true
 }
 ],
 "oLanguage": {
      "sEmptyTable": "No Records found."
 }
 });
```

The data contains more than 15 thousands of records, it contains the flag like 'Open' OR 'Close'. Currently I am using the for loop to sort the data and bind it to the data - table. Means if data have 15 thousand of records and it contains 7 thousands of 'Open' flag records, it takes long time to sort & bind the data to Datatable. Hence Is there any way to check the condition in 'columns:' if flag is not 'Open' then continue to the next iteration??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter method to first filter the objects with 'open' status in the array.

```
someObject.columns.filter(x => x.data == 'open')
```

This will filter out only those with the flag 'open'. You can cache it into a variable for further work.

Comment: **@Ilya Kushlianski**, Currently I am doing same thing using for loop to sort and bind the data. I am asking is their any other way? So that at the time of binding the data I am checking the condition